# Include Path issue with config and header

Tags: php

I have a problem with include path in PHP.

Code:
https://github.com/kukubaczek/KukuShop/blob/master/www/panel/index.php

If i open the panel/index.php page I see this error's:

> Warning: require_once(/parts/header.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in /PATH/KukuShop/www/panel/index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/parts/header.php' (include_path='/..') in
>   /PATH/KukuShop/www/panel/index.php on line 3

How can I fix this? Here is problem with include path.

Answer (score 1):

You are using absolute references when you probably want relative file locations. Try using this instead:

```
require_once("../parts/header.php")
```

Comment: In header.php path is "../config/main.php". In www/index.php config is working but in www/panel/index.php don't working.

Comment: Yes, you need to change that line in the panel/index.php page. Also, you may want to remove (or comment out) the set_include_path statement on the line above it.

Comment: Code: <?php
 require_once('../parts/header.php');
?>

Result:
Serwer.pl
Użyj Voucher.
// Panel administratora 
Warning: require_once(/parts/footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Volumes/Mac HD 2/Kuba/Dropbox/HTML/KukuShop/www/panel/index.php on line 8

Comment: You need to make that same fix for the require_once("/parts/footer.php") as well.

Answer (score 0):

What does the directory structure look like?

The `set_include_path('/..');` statement doesn't seem to make sense.

Your PHP installation can't seem to find the files.